# How to create an EAR from a Java Application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, ejb, ear

I created a Java application, and I want to put it into an EAR to be uploaded to Websphere Application Server and start it. It's not a web project, it's a java application project only.

I heard that maybe with EJB I could, can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use your IDE to export an enterprise application project into an EAR file.

If you are using **Eclipse** then you can follow these steps:

1. In the Java™ EE perspective, click **File > Export**.
2. Under **Select an export destination**, click **J2EE > EAR file**, and then click **Next**.
3. In the **EAR project** list, select the enterprise application project you want to export.
4. In the **Destination** field, enter the full path and EAR file name where you want to export the enterprise application project that is selected in the **EAR application** field.
5. **Optional**: To export source files, select the **Export source files** check box.
6. **Optional**: If you are exporting to an existing EAR file and you do not want to be warned about overwriting it, select the **Overwrite existing file** check box.
7. Click **Finish**.

The wizard exports the contents of the EAR project to the specified EAR file. Additionally, for each project that corresponds to a module or utility JAR in the application, the project contents are exported into a nested module or JAR file in the EAR file. If any unsaved changes exist on any of the files in any of the referenced projects, you are prompted to save these files prior to export.

Comment: I am sorry i got it wrong, why don't you package your source code as a jar file, and use it as a module in WebSphere. If you are using Maven and then just install that jar in maven as dependency.

Comment: Do you have, by the way, an example of how to deploy a jar file in WAS as module? (Note: I'm not using maven)

Comment: @Xanathos  Sorry i am working in JBoss so i am more familiar with it, give me sometime to find its counter part for WebSphere. But in the meantime keep it inside the lib folder and i hope you would be able to work out, but the best is to declare modules in server.

Answer (score -2):

Maven is the build tool of choice for many people due to the simplicity and flexibility of use. The real strength of Maven is vetted when handling real complex projetcs consisting of tens of modules, each requiring elaborate build requirements.

There are some URL, introduction how to create ear package.

- [Creating an EAR with Maven](http://palashray.com/2010/08/22/creating-an-ear-with-maven/)
- [Generating an EAR that runs in IBM WebSphere Process Server](http://mojo.codehaus.org/was6-maven-plugin/examples/generating-process-server-ears.html)

Comment: Broken links. If possible refer to the contents of the Stack Overflow itself.